# How does Java handle vulnerable code coming as input arguments?

Tags: java, security, static-analysis

How does jvm handle vulnerable code like 'System.exit()' when passed as user inputs?

Comment: It doesn't.  Are you writing a program that executes its user input?

Comment: What do you mean by 'code passed as user inputs?' There is no interpreter in Java.

Comment: @bmargulies: Interpreters are a pretty normal thing to have in Java implementations. [HotSpot has one.](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/hotspot/) There's just no built-in `eval`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java has no function like `eval()` in JavaScript for executing Java code on the fly.

There are only two alternative ways to load code:

1. If the app allows to load compiled code (Java classes) from a user defined file (e.g. using a ClassLoader)
2. If the app uses `ObjectInputStream` for deserializing data (and the correspondent class byte code which is included).

Both ways are vulnerabel to malicious code, hence loaded code can execute anything.

The only way Java provides are Security Managers - which were mainly used in Java Applets. However this way is IMHO obsolete because there was always a way to bypass the Security Manager restrictions. One of the main reasons why Java applets are obsolete nowadays.

Comment: Plus one for your answer! A couple of notes. 1) Apps. launched using Java Web Start also gained a security manager, but that's equally irrelevant since JWS is also deprecated. 2) Any app. can create and install a security manager. But.. 3) The (default) security managers never tried to detect things like a DOS attack (e.g. by starting an infinite thread that ties up the CPU). So .. while a security manager might at first glance look like a way to approach this, they really cannot be effective at protecting against user error / malicious users.